# Dynamically updating slow log in ES 2.4.1?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to enable slow log for my Elasticsearch 2.4.1.But when i tried it dynamically, it is showing error for me ?

```
PUT _cluster/settings
     {
      "transient": {
        "index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug": "0s",
        "index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug": "0s",
        "index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.debug": "0s"
      }
    }
```

The response in logs

```
[2017-02-22 12:44:33,650][WARN ][action.admin.cluster.settings] [Powderkeg] igno
ring transient setting [index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.trace], not dynam
ically updateable
[2017-02-22 12:44:33,651][WARN ][action.admin.cluster.settings] [Powderkeg] igno
ring transient setting [index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.trace], not dynamic
ally updateable
[2017-02-22 12:44:33,651][WARN ][action.admin.cluster.settings] [Powderkeg] igno
ring transient setting [index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.trace], not dynamic
ally updateable
[2017-02-22 13:58:30,051][WARN ][action.admin.cluster.settings] [Powderkeg] igno
ring transient setting [index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.debug], not dynam
ically updateable
[2017-02-22 13:58:30,051][WARN ][action.admin.cluster.settings] [Powderkeg] igno
ring transient setting [index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug], not dynamic
ally updateable
[2017-02-22 13:58:30,052][WARN ][action.admin.cluster.settings] [Powderkeg] igno
ring transient setting [index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug], not dynamic
ally updateable
```

Answer (score 2):

This settings should be given at index level not cluster level.

```
PUT indexname/_settings
     {

        "index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug": "0s",
        "index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug": "0s",
        "index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.debug": "0s"

    }
```

Comment: You should probably edit the question then. It seems like you want to enable the log cluster wide.

Comment: I think these settings we can't enable at cluster wide these are dynamic and are set per-index https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html